# React update component after CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I am building a React web application that has CRUD operations on a table connected to a database. I am using axios in React components to make ajax calls to the backend controller. The Customers component displays a list of records from my table. When I create, delete or edit a record from the database the Customers component is not automatically refreshing. I have to refresh the page in order to get the updated records my database. I had a look at lifting the state up but I don't understand why its not working as the Customers component is already the parent.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import EditCustomerModal from './EditCustomerModal';
import AddCustomerModal from './AddCustomerModal';
import DeleteCustomerModal from './DeleteCustomerModal';

export class Customers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { customers: [] };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateCustomerData();
  }

  render() {

    let customers = this.state.customers;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header as='h2'>Customer Table</Header>
        <p>This component demonstrates CRUD operations from the customer table.</p>

        <AddCustomerModal />

        <Table striped>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell textAlign="center">Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>

          <Table.Body>
            {customers.map((customer) => {
              return (
                <Table.Row key={customer.id}>
                  <Table.Cell>{customer.id}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{customer.name}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{customer.address}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell textAlign="center">

                    <EditCustomerModal details={customer} />
                    <DeleteCustomerModal customerID={customer.id} />

                  </Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>

              )
            })}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table >
      </div>
    );
  }

  populateCustomerData = () => {
    axios.get("Customers/GetCustomers")
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ customers: result.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of state management technique are you using to update the state ?
EDIT: You can't expect to delete something from the database and the result to be shown on the page. If you delete something from the application and update the state, then the result will be shown, otherwise it'll be shown only when refreshing and accessing the data from the DB.

Comment: You should refetch from DB your edited element and update it from your list OR refetch all list if you are lazy. Both methods require a props passed from parent component <Customers /> to child components <EditCustomerModal /> and <DeleteCustomerModal />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a changeState function from your Customers Component to your modals and call it after a crud operation has been done.

OR

You can pass your populateCustomerData function to the modals and make them call it after the crud operation has been done.

Comment: Should the changeState function be checking the customers[] state within Customers component?

Comment: The changeState function should receive an updated list of customers and set them in state.

You define it inside your Customers component and pass the function as a prop to the child components IE, the CRUD modals.
They call the function with the updated customer list after they finished their operation.